# I keep having "Unresolved reference" in my code

Tags: python, mobile, kivy, kivymd

Here, I am trying to bing some actions to the "plus" and "trash-can-outline" icons. After some research, I have seen that I could do that by creating a whole class and them instantiating the class. But for some reason, I keep having this error message. Help, please!

I was expecting this to work just fine. And mind you, I also tried putting the parentheses at the end of the function when calling; still the same problem.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem, IconLeftWidget, OneLineAvatarIconListItem, IconRightWidget


class MyListItem(OneLineAvatarIconListItem):
    def __init__(self, icon_left_action, icon_right_action, **kwargs):
        super(MyListItem, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.icon_left = IconLeftWidget(icon='plus')
        self.icon_left.bind(on_release=icon_left_action)

        self.icon_right = IconRightWidget(icon='trash-can-outline')
        self.icon_right.bind(on_release=icon_right_action)


class EntityDialogContent(MDBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(EntityDialogContent, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class SubTaskDialogContent(MDBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SubTaskDialogContent, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class myApp(MDApp):

    #Define the database and initialize the lists
    database_file = 'database.txt'
    entity_list_dialog = None
    subtask_list_dialog = None

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('main.kv')

    def on_start(self):
        self.load_entities_from_file()


    def load_entities_from_file(self):
        # Creating the empty dictionary
        try:
            with open(self.database_file, "r") as file:
                lines = file.readlines()
                for line in lines:
                    entity_text = line.strip()
                    if entity_text:
                        # print("Loaded entity:", entity_text)  # Add this line for debugging
                        item = MyListItem(icon_left_action = subtask_dialog,
                            icon_right_action = delete_entity,
                            text=entity_text[1:])
                        self.root.ids.container.add_widget(item)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("File not found")

    # Setting the dialog boxes
    def entity_dialog(self):
        if self.entity_list_dialog:
            self.entity_list_dialog.dismiss()

        self.entity_list_dialog = MDDialog(
            title="Create Entities",
            type="custom",
            content_cls=EntityDialogContent()
        )
        self.entity_list_dialog.open()

    def subtask_dialog(self):
        if self.subtask_list_dialog:
            self.subtask_list_dialog.dismiss()

        self.entity_list_dialog = MDDialog(
            title="Create Subtasks",
            type="custom",
            content_cls=SubTaskDialogContent()
        )
        self.subtask_list_dialog.open()

# Adding Entities and subtasks
    def add_entity(self):
        entity_text = self.entity_list_dialog.content_cls.ids.entity_text.text
        if entity_text.strip():
            with open(self.database_file, "a") as file:
                file.write("*" + entity_text + "\n")

                item = OneLineAvatarIconListItem(
                    IconLeftWidget(icon = 'plus'), IconRightWidget(icon = 'trash-can-outline'),
                            text=entity_text)
                self.root.ids.container.add_widget(item)
                self.entity_list_dialog.content_cls.ids.entity_text.text = ""


    def add_subtask(self):
        subtask_text = self.subtask_list_dialog.content_cls.ids.subtask_text.text
        if subtask_text.strip():
            with open(self.database_file, "a") as file:
                file.write("-" + subtask_text + "\n")

                item = OneLineAvatarIconListItem(
                            # IconRightWidget(icon = 'plus'),
                            text=subtask_text)
                self.root.ids.container.add_widget(item)
                self.subtask_list_dialog.content_cls.ids.subtask_text.text = ""

#Deleting tasks and Subtasks

    def delete_entity(self):
        pass

# Closing Dialogs
    def close_entity_dialog(self, *args):
        self.entity_list_dialog.dismiss()

    def close_subtask_dialog(self):
        self.subtask_list_dialog.dismiss()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = myApp()
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that you are missing `self` in the following code:

```
                    item = MyListItem(icon_left_action = subtask_dialog,
                        icon_right_action = delete_entity,
                        text=entity_text[1:])
```

Try changing it to:

```
                    item = MyListItem(icon_left_action = self.subtask_dialog,
                        icon_right_action = self.delete_entity,
                        text=entity_text[1:])
```

Comment: This worked. But do you have any idea why my icons are not appearing in my list?